# mock a function which is inside another function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function need to be tested, which looks like this:

```
def f1(var):
    def f2(var):
        # some ops based on var
        # return the result

    ret = f2(var)
    # ops
```

In my unit test, I wanted to mock the return value of f2, which is inside f1.

I tried to mock it with

```
f1.f2.return_value
```

and

```
f2.return_value
```

but both were failed.

So how could I mock the f2 inside f1,

or should I refactor the code to move f2 out of f1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is almost certainly some way to access f2 inside of f1 and and make a stub for it in unittesting, it will almost certainly be cleaner to refactor and move f2 out of f1. Something like this:

```
def f1(var):
    ret = f2(var)

def f2(var):
   # some ops based on var
   return result
```